# How to get the Value of a Cell from a TableView to Another View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm going to make this VERY simple because for the past week people are getting confused with this same exact question. I have on TableViewController. When a user taps on a cell on my TableViewController it goes to a **DetailViewController** which has a button called **PAID**. When the user taps on the PAID button in the **DETAILVIEWCONTROLLER** I want that specific cell that I tapped in the **HISTORYTABLEVIEWCONTROLLER** to be marked PAID. I don't care how it gets marked I just want it done. Im using core data and I've already created a "paid" attribute. So I would also like the cell to be **SAVED** as **PAID.**

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Sincerely, About to throw my iMac out the window

Comment: Could you post you `didSelectRow` method? That is the best place to start. Also, **what** goes to your detail view controller?

Comment: you can make use of blocks to set particular property in previous 
ViewController

Answer (score 0):

There a multiple ways you could accomplish this. One way is to pass both the managedObjectContext, and the selected managedObject to the detail controller. In the "Paid" button's action method, set the value of the "paid" attribute for that passed in object, and call save: on the managedObjectContext. As far as marking the cell, you should have that (a string "Paid" or whatever other kind of mark you want) tied to the value of the "paid" attribute, so once your database is updated, that should be reflected in the table view.

Answer (score 0):

If you use core data, It will be quite simple to achieve this.

1. In your detail view, modify paid attribute in core data, and save.
2. In table view controller, observe **NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification** notification. If core data changed, notification callback will get called. Then change the tableview's datasource and update table cell.